# Sequence of functions that extends the algebraic properties of exponents to higher level operators.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions

I was thinking about some simple algebraic exponent properties such as the following
$$
z^{x+y} = z^xz^y
$$
and I started wondering about analytically continuing this identity to "higher-level operators" if that makes any sense. I thought about the following idea: define
$$
O_1(x, y) = x+y \\
O_2(x, y) = xy \\
O_3(x, y) = x^y
$$
and let these be the first three functions in a set of functions $O_n$ from $\Bbb{R}_+^2\to\Bbb{R}_+$. Starting with $O_1$, $O_2$ and $O_3$ above, is it possible to find $O_n$ such that for all integers $n \ge 3$
$$
O_n(z,\ O_{n-2}(x,\ y)) = O_{n-1}(O_n(z,\ x),\ O_n(z,\ y))?
$$
**EDIT:** Maybe to make it more obvious why I want the above relation to hold, it's because the identity $z^{xy} = z^xz^y$ is equivalent to $O_3(z,\ O_1(x,\ y)) = O_2(O_3(z,\ x),\ O_3(z,\ y))$.

Comment: Well,  $z^{xy}\ne z^{x}z^{y}$ in general.

Comment: @Dr.MV Good point, how about for $x, y, z \in \Bbb{R}_+$?

Comment: $z^{xy}=(z^x)^y$ whereas $z^xz^y=z^{x+y}$.

Comment: Whoops! Wow, let me rephrase the question.

Comment: That sounds good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out $O_4$ and $O_5$ are constants both equal to $1$, and then you don't have sufficient information to determine $O_n$ for $n\ge6$. From the identity in the original question, we have
$$
O_4(z, xy) = O_4(z, x)^{O_4(z, y)} \\
\ln{O_4(z, xy)} = O_4(z, y)\ln{O_4(z, x)}.
$$
Substituting $x = 0$ gives us
$$
\ln{O_4(z, 0)} = O_4(z, y)\ln{O_4(z, 0)} \\
O_4(z, y) = 1
$$
thus $O_4(x, y) = 1$. A similar procedure can be followed to determine $O_5(x, y) = 1$. Then when we get to $O_6$ we have
$$
O_6(z, 1) = 1
$$
from the original identity. This is not enough information to determine $O_6(x, y)$. Similarly, we can't determine $O_7$ or anything higher because we end up with
$$
O_{n\ge6}(z, 1) = 1.
$$